# How can I write math notation on the Mathematica site?

Tags: support, new-users, site-tools

I want to ask some questions in the Mathematics site. But I don't know how to write the proper math notations in the computer. 
For example how to write

- x^y ( where x is raised to power y).
- sign of congruence. ( x is congruengt = 1 (mod y) )

or other math notations. Is there any chart or link from where i can copy while typing my questions? or some other resource?

Comment: The title mentions Mathematica (ending with A), but the text mentions Mathematics (with an S). You have to realize these are two different things addressed at two different StackExchange sites. Are you here for the software product or the science? In the latter case you should go to http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3):

On the right-hand side our *Ask a Question* page, there is a box titled *How to Format*. It gives condensed instructions on formatting question, mainly -- I think -- as reminders to those with some experience with the site. At the bottom right of the box there are three links to pages that provide instructions of more use to newcomers. You should follow those links.

The box looks this.

[image: formatting]

The *MathJaX help* link will take you to a page providing info on formatting mathematical expressions in traditional form, but use of MathJaX should be kept to a minimum. We prefer problems to stated in terms of *Mathematic* code, which should be formatted with markdown as explained on page you will go to when you click on the *formatting help* link.